# Nginx mail proxy: tls between the proxy and the server?

Tags: nginx, email, smtp, email-server, starttls

When using the [Nginx Mail Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/) feature to realize an SMTP proxy, there are [several options](https://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_ssl_module.html) available to configure (start)tls between the client and the proxy.

However, it appears between the proxy and the upstream SMTP server, only 'plain' SMTP is supported, and there is no way to enable either STARTTLS or regular TLS.

Can anyone confirm this? Or is there a way to securely connect (and authenticate) to the upstream SMTP server?

Comment: I setup a nginx mail proxy that I want clients to connect without encryption and then the proxy to connect to real mail server using TLS or SSL. Did you found out if Nginx support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is indeed not possible using just Nginx, I since successfully combined it with [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: For your own answer with stunnel, can you use nginx stream module to handle tls?